# Trying to create multidimensional array from mysql query, php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Trying to combine two query into array. Look at my code, first, I want to get all fruit have cat A and val good. second, I will get the mark that fruit match first query, cat c and the val either OK or bad. At last, I want to make them array like 
$arg = ('apple'=>'4','banana'=>'2','pear'=>'0'); because pear did not match val OK or bad, so 0. Do you have any way to do it? appreciate.

```html
<?php
/*
fruit  cat     val    mark
apple   A      good    V
apple   c       OK     4
banana  A      good     W
banana  c      bad     2
pear    A      good     W
pear    c      good     8
*/
$val1 = 'OK';
$val2 = 'bad';
$result1 = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
 SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM my_table WHERE cat ='A' AND val='%s' ",$val1));

$result2 = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
 SELECT mark FROM my_table WHERE cat ='c' AND val='%s' AND fruit IN (SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM my_table WHERE cat ='A' AND val='%s')",$val2,$val1));

/*how can I combine these two queries into an array like 
$arg = ('apple'=>'4','banana'=>'2','pear'=>'0');
because pear did not match, so 0
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to rewrite the query, instead of doing it manually in php, I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT
  t.fruit,
  CASE
    WHEN t.a_mark IS NOT NULL THEN t.a_mark
    WHEN t.c_mark IS NOT NULL THEN t.c_mark
    ELSE '0'
  END mark
FROM
  (SELECT
    t.fruit,
    ( SELECT MAX(mark)
      FROM my_table
      WHERE fruit = t.fruit AND val = 'good' AND cat = 'A'
        AND mark NOT IN ('V', 'W')) a_mark,
    ( SELECT MAX(mark)
      FROM my_table
      WHERE fruit = t.fruit AND val in ('OK', 'bad') AND cat = 'c'
        AND mark NOT IN ('V', 'W')) c_mark  
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM my_table) t
  ) t
ORDER BY
  t.fruit
```